# Highlight text defined by pattern

Tags: regex, highlighting, vim

I'd like to highlight certain part of the text before the cursor and certain part of the text after the cursor.
The parts before and after the cursor will be defined by some pattern (like regular expression). This pattern should not be limited by line.
The highlighted area will change as the cursor will move.

Is this possible in vim settings or script?

Comment: What do you mean in that "...will change as the cursor will move"? If it is highlighted based on regex, then it doesn't matter where the cursor is. Or have I completely misunderstood your meaning?

Comment: Assume the cursor <C> is in [this](http://pastebin.com/fAapn94V) string and you want to highlight substring defined by two points 1) closest capital letter before cursor 2) closest dot after the cursor. The sentence "It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged." will be highlighted. When you move the cursor another sentence will be highlighted.

Comment: Note that the highlighted string spreads over many lines (here two).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically, both of the following commands should work:

```
match Error /\v\u\_\U{-}%#\_.{-}\./
syn match Error /\v\u\_\U{-}%#\_.{-}\./
```

. Eventually, with both commands I observe a bug: highlight is not updated properly until I hit `<C-l>`. More, with `:syn match` it sometimes highlights two different parts of two different sentences, so first one is more preferred (also see `:h matchadd()` and `:h 2match` because `:match` highlighting may disappear because it AFAIR is used also by something else).

**Update**: Though due to the bug described above I would not recommend adding it to the vimrc, you can use the following:

```
augroup vimrcSentenceMatch
    autocmd!
    autocmd WinEnter * : if !exists('w:sentence_match') 
                     \ |     let w:sentence_match=matchadd('Error', '\v\u\_\U{-}%#\_.{-}\.')
                     \ | endif
augroup END
```

Comment: What's the pattern here? Could be possible an easy pattern as I mention in comment under the question?

Comment: @xralf. It is exactly what you mentioned in comment: “substring defined by two points 1) closest capital letter before cursor 2) closest dot after the cursor”. First point is `\u\_\U{-}`, second is `\_.{-}\.`. `%#` means “cursor position”, `\v` makes me able to omit some backslashes (“very magic” mode), `\_` in both expressions extends character classes (`\u` is uppercase latin letter, `\U` is the everything, but newline or uppercase latin letter, `.` is just any character except newline) with newline.

Comment: Note: there is no vim atom that stands for “capital letter”, only for “capital *latin* letter”.

Comment: I added the code to my *.vimrc* but it does nothing (I can't see no effect).

Comment: @xralf Which of the lines? Try `augroup vimrcSentenceMatch`+`autocmd!`+`autocmd WinEnter * if !exists('w:sentence_match') | let w:sentence_match=matchadd('Error', '\v\u\_\U{-}%#\_.{-}\.') | endif`+`augroup END` (each on its own line) (and, probably, `doautocmd vimrcSentenceMatch WinEnter`). The `syntax` statement will be overriden by any syntax loaded for given file, `match` is window-local and thus should be defined for every new window. Both lines were intended for manual or mapping launch after buffer was loaded, not for addition to vimrc.

Comment: And all of them must slow down your vim significantly if you are able to deal with “match not updated” issue.

Comment: Could you please paste it to pastebin? This gives me syntax error.

Comment: I tried it but the highlighting is not changing with cursor movements.

Comment: OK, seems this can't be done as I'd like, but wait for some time yet.

Comment: @xralf Actually this bug looks like a compromise between performance and proper highlighting. I would not expect it to be fixed soon, though you may definitely try something like `autocmd CursorMoved,CursorMovedI * :if line('.')!=get(b:, 'lastline', 0) | redraw | let b:lastline=line('.') | endif` (maybe `!` is needed after `:redraw`, I have not tested this). It will slow your vim down, but I do not know how significant this slowdown will be.

Comment: Slight slow down is OK. I don't need to be fast here. But on my vim it's quite buggy. It even does not highlight sentence surrounding the cursor, it behaves quite randomly.

Comment: @xralf: For me it works almost fine except 1. CursorMoved is launched only when you move between lines, not when you move inside a line. 2. Bang *is* needed after `:redraw`. 3. If you are at the first character of the sentence you will get two sentences highlighted.